# C# Sockets send/receive problems and questions

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Good morning all,

First of all apologies for the somewhat generic title. If in the course of this message I can come up with something a little more detailed, I will certainly change it.

I am working on a project that will contain 3 programs. The purpose is to be able to send a notification to all clients connected. For this there is a server, client, and console program.
The message itself will be an RTF file, but the notification also requires a sending department (string), and a display timer (TimeSpan).

Most of the project is done. The logic is mostly complete, it is multithreaded, all the classes are ready, and most tests work.

The problem I am having is that the server seems to not receive the data from the console in the right order. Thereby causing all sorts of problems.

The process from console to server is as follows:

1. Console first selects all relevant information for the notification:

   - Users (List, gathered from LDAP)
   - Expiration date and time (DateTime)
   - Time before close is allowed (long, amount of ticks)
   - Department (string)
   - RTF file
2. The server is already active, and has a separate thread for the console connections
3. Console connects to server
4. Server creates a separate thread to handle the console connection
5. Console sends the username of the logged on user to the server
6. Server checks whether user is allowed to create notification (for now it will always return true)
7. Console sends all the relevant information in the following order:

   - MessageID (string)
   - RecipientCount (number of users, used to loop appropriately from server side)
   - Recipients (foreach loop of List)
   - Department (string)
   - VisibleTime (long)
   - Expiration (DateTime)
   - and finally RTF file

I have used System.Diagnostics.Trace to check whether all information is sent correctly, and in the right order. This all checks out. But the thing is that roughly 75% of the time the server side seems to receive the RTF file at the moment it should be receiving the visibleTime.

The code is as follows:

```
private void SendMessage()
{
    SendToServer(Environment.UserName);
    if (bool.Parse(ReadFromServer()))
    {
        // User is allowed, continue
        string messageID = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks.ToString();
        SendToServer(messageID); // MessageID

        string recipientCount = lvRecipients.Items.Count.ToString();              
        SendToServer(lvRecipients.Items.Count.ToString()); // Amount of recipients

        foreach (string item in lvRecipients.Items) // Loop to send each recipient
        {
            SendToServer(item);
        }

        string department = TB_Department.Text;
        SendToServer(department); // Send department string

        string visibleTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SLIDER_VisibleTime.Value).Ticks.ToString();
        SendToServer(visibleTime); // Send message visibility time

        string expiration = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(2).ToString();
        SendToServer(expiration); //TODO add UI control for this

        SendRTFToServer(); // Send RTF file

        MessageBox.Show(
            "Your designated MessageID is: " + messageID + Environment.NewLine +
            "Message upload is succesful.",
            "Complete",
            MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        // User is not allowed. Report to user. Disconnect (will be managed by the finally block)
        MessageBox.Show(
                "You are not allowed to upload messages to the server.",
                "Access denied",
                MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Stop);
        return;
    }

}


private void SendToServer(string toSend)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server.GetStream());
    writer.WriteLine(toSend);
    writer.Flush();
}


private void SendRTFToServer()
{
    StreamReader rtfFile = new StreamReader(File.Open(RTFLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(server.GetStream());
    sw.Write(rtfFile.ReadToEnd());
    sw.Flush();
    server.GetStream().Flush();
}

private string ReadFromServer()
{
    server.GetStream().Flush();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server.GetStream());
    return reader.ReadLine();
}
```

And from the server:

```
private void Connect()
{
    string username = ReadFromConsole();

    if (IsUserAllowed(username)) // Receive username
        SendToConsole(bool.TrueString); // Send confirmation
    else
    {
        SendToConsole(bool.FalseString); // Send denial
        console.Close();
        return;
    }

    string messageID = ReadFromConsole(); // Receive MessageID

    string recipientCount = ReadFromConsole();

    int numOfRecipients = int.Parse(recipientCount); // Receive and parse number of recipients

    List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRecipients; i++)
    {
        string recipient = ReadFromConsole();
        recipients.Add(recipient); // Receive recipient, add to list (required for Message)
    }

    string department = ReadFromConsole(); // Receive department string

    string visibleTime = ReadFromConsole();

    string expiration = ReadFromConsole();

    StoreRTF(messageID); // Receive and store RTF file

    console.Close(); // Connection is done, close

    Message message = new Message(messageID, department, recipients, visibleTime, expiration);
}

private void SendToConsole(string toSend)
{
    // Open client stream, and write information to it.
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(console.GetStream());
    writer.WriteLine(toSend);
    writer.Flush();
}

private string ReadFromConsole()
{    
    // Read information from client stream
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(console.GetStream());
    return reader.ReadLine();
}

private void StoreRTF(string messageID)
{
    // Check/create folder for Message storage
    string messageFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\BMNotify\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(messageFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(messageFolder);

    // Create file to store message in
    Stream rtfFile = File.Create(messageFolder + messageID + ".rtf");

    // Store information from stream, and close resources
    console.GetStream().CopyTo(rtfFile);
    rtfFile.Close();
    rtfFile.Dispose();

}
```

And the message class:

```
public class Message
{
    internal string messageID;
    internal string department;
    internal List<string> recipients;
    internal TimeSpan visibleAtLeast;
    internal DateTime messageExpiration;

    private static List<Message> allMessages; // Will hold te collection of Message's

    public Message(string _messageID, string _department, List<string> _recipients, string visibleTime, string expiration)
    {
        messageID = _messageID;
        recipients = _recipients;
        department = _department;

        visibleAtLeast = TimeSpan.FromTicks(long.Parse(visibleTime));
        messageExpiration = DateTime.Parse(expiration);

        if (allMessages == null)
            allMessages = new List<Message>(); // Initialize if required

        allMessages.Add(this);
    }

    internal Stream GetRTF()
    {
        return File.Open
            (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\BMNotify\" + messageID + ".rtf",
            FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read, 
            FileShare.Read);
    }

    static public List<Message> AllMessages()
    {
        if (allMessages == null)
            allMessages = new List<Message>(); // Initialize if required

        return allMessages;
    }

    static public void RemoveMessage(Message message)
    {
        allMessages.Remove(message);
    }
}
```

If anyone could shed any light on this, or tell me what I should change.. Or basically anything that could get me going again, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Try to run it single threading and see if the problem persists, if it doesn't you'll need some sort of queuing mechanism. Another tip: try to keep your questions short and simple, it will force you to pinpoint your actual problem and will result in much more answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I will try and see if that works and report back.
(Also, thanks for the tip. I will keep it in mind. Reason for all the code is to show that I am not looking for someone else to do my work, but am genuinely stuck/stupified)

Comment: Just checked, but the problem remains. It seems centered on receiving the recipients. At that time it starts to receive the RTF file. Even stepping through the code one step at a time doesn't remedy this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may stem from the fact that you're using a `StreamReader` to read data from the connection. Internally `StreamReader` buffers data it reads from the underlying `Stream`. You are creating a new `StreamReader` every time you attempt to read from the connection, and then discarding it once you've read a single line. In doing so, you're also discarding any data read from the connection that was buffered by the `StreamReader` (which may have constituted all or part of the following fields).

You should probably attempt to create a single `StreamReader` on the network stream, and use that same instance for all reads.

Comment: Just implemented this, and it seems to be working!! Will have to modify the remaining programs, but will report back soon.
I almost can't believe that I have overlooked something this simple!

Comment: Moved all read/write operations to a single StreamReader and StreamWriter, and everything works perfectly. Also been able to clean up and simplify the code.
Thank you very much!